# Computer Architecture: Cache Speed Analysis

Tags: performance, caching, cpu-architecture

I have this question on my exam study guide and cannot figure out how to do it:

Consider three processors with different cache configurations:  
Cache 1: Direct mapped with one-word blocks  
Cache 2: Direct mapped with four-word blocks  
Cache 3: Two-way set associative with four-word blocks

The following miss rate measurements have been made: 
Cache 1: Instruction miss rate is 4%; data miss rate is 6%  
Cache 2: Instruction miss rate is 2%; data miss rate is 4%  
Cache 3: Instruction miss rate is 2%; data miss rate is 3%

a) For these processors, one-half of the instructions contain a data reference. Assume that cache miss 
penalty is 6 plus the block size in words. The CPI for this workload was measured on processor with 
cache 1 and was found to be 2.0. Determine which processor spends most cycles on a cache miss. Show 
your work.

b) The cycle times for the processors above are 420ps for the first and second processors and 310ps for the third processor. Determine which processor is the fastest and which is the slowest. Show your work.

For part A, I found the penalties to be 7, 10, and 10 for caches 1, 2, and 3 respectively, by using 6+1, 6+4, and 6+4.  From this I would assume that the most cycles are spend on caches 2 and 3, but that would completely answer part A and the info about CPI never came into play.  Does that seem right?
I haven't done anything with part B yet because I think that depends on part A.

Comment: You ignored that fact that cache1 has almost 2x more misses. You have the penalties per a *single* miss, now calculate the overall penalty given how many instructions and data accesses you have, and the respective miss rates

Comment: So would I do something like this for the first cache and similarly for the other two: 7*50*(.04+.06) = 35 Cycles?
(where the 50 comes from assuming 100 instructions)